# How to import CSS to React (electron.js) Project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron

I create a simple react/electron project with "electron-forge" plugin : `electron-forge init myProject --template=react`. I try to import my css file with this code below

Button.module.css

```
.error {
    color: red;
}
```

app.jsx - created by electron-forge:

```
import React from 'react';

import styles from './Button.module.css'; // Import css modules stylesheet as styles

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Hello world</h1>
        <button className={styles.error}>Error Button</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

It throws an error: 
`Uncaught Error: Couldn't find a compiler for /home/denny/Experimentals/electron-transactionsell/src/Button.module.css`

I'm pretty sure I have the file in the correct folder
and I am sure that this is how it's done in React
https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet

[image: my project structure]

Comment: Try ending all your import lines with semicolon, ;

Comment: @chidimo and... how's that supposed to help ? I add semicolon to my import lines, and as I expected, it still throws `Uncaught Error: Cannot find module '/lib/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css`

Comment: I thought it might help cos Javascript requires semicolon to end every code block. And the error you're seeing indicates a syntax error. Now you have to try looking at your syntax a bit closer

Comment: If you have fontawesome and ionic icons in your node_modules folder then you should import them from there instead of from lib. Google the exact syntax.

Comment: @chidimo OK. maybe you're right. I remove any library that I have and just focusing to add my own css file. I edited my question to be simpler. and it throws a different error this time: `Uncaught Error: Couldn't find a compiler for Button.module.css`

Comment: I think that is as far as my contribution goes. I have no experience with electron. I could only comment on the JS side of things.

Comment: @chidimo Thanks. much appreciated. I'm still confused on how is it work on react but not on electron + react